# Factor Analysis: calculate maximum likelihood factor loadings from only the correlation (R) matrix and/or covariance (S) matrix?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, maximum-likelihood, factor-analysis, covariance-matrix

Does anybody know how to calculate the maximum likelihood factor loadings from *only* the correlation (R) matrix and/or covariance (S) matrix in Factor Analysis "by hand" (i.e., by Excel)?  Or, even better, point me to a clear explanation with a worked example?

I don't have the underlying data, so I can't just use a software program to solve the problem for me.  (Any answer involving typical FA software commands or menu sequences won't be helpful, I don't think.)

To the extent it's helpful, I'm using Johnson and Wichern's "Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis", 6th Edition.  In the exercises in Chapter 9, we're given just the R or S matrix and then asked to perform the maximum likelihood calculation repeatedly (e.g., exercises 9.20 b; 9.24, 9.26, and 9.27), yet the book never shows an example (as far as I can tell, nor does the answer key, which my professor makes available to us).

Thanks in advance and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the source code for the `factanal` function in R. It is possible to provide a covariance or correlation matrix as an argument.

- [You can see the source code here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/factanal.R?source=c)
- Or it would probably be more useful to type `debug(factanal)` and then run the `factanal` function with a sample correlation matrix. You could then inspect the effect of each step.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I hate to admit this, but I don't know how to run custom packages in R (I'm very new to R).  And I can't find this package in the standard R library.  Any tips about how I can run this script?  If the answer is I just need to get up to speed on R, so be it!

Comment: There's nothing custom about `factanal` it's a built-in function in base R. You can just load R and type `factanal` into the R console and you'll see the code for the function. That said, if you're new to R, you may find following the code challenging.